# Salt installation in rhel 5.4

Tags: python, python-2.6, salt-stack, rhel5

I am trying to install `salt-2016.11.3-2.el5.noarch.rpm` in rhel5. For that I compiled python 2.6

```
[root@localhost bin]# ls -lrt python*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    8304 Jun 11  2009 python2.4
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5733122 Sep 11 11:52 python2.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5733122 Sep 11 11:52 python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Sep 11 11:53 python-config -> python2.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1418 Sep 11 11:53 python2.6-config
```

After I tried to install salt-minion which is showing this deps.

```
[root@localhost minion]# rpm -ivh salt-2016.11.3-2.el5.noarch.rpm
warning: salt-2016.11.3-2.el5.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 signature: NOKEY, key ID 42e589e9
error: Failed dependencies:
        **/usr/bin/python2.6 is needed by salt-2016.11.3-2.el5.noarch**
        python26-PyYAML is needed by salt-2016.11.3-2.el5.noarch
        python26-crypto >= 2.6.1 is needed by salt-2016.11.3-2.el5.noarch
        python26-jinja2 is needed by salt-2016.11.3-2.el5.noarch
        python26-msgpack > 0.3 is needed by salt-2016.11.3-2.el5.noarch
        python26-requests >= 1.0.0 is needed by salt-2016.11.3-2.el5.noarch
        python26-six is needed by salt-2016.11.3-2.el5.noarch
        python26-tornado >= 4.2.1 is needed by salt-2016.11.3-2.el5.noarch
        yum-utils is needed by salt-2016.11.3-2.el5.noarch
```

I already installed python and its available in PATH. Still why its showing that deps. Anyone faced the same issue??? Any suggestions are welcome.

**Note:**

the main issue is

`/usr/bin/python2.6 is needed by salt-2016.11.3-2.el5.noarch`

Why python is showing in the dependency list which is already installed???

Comment: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/30227

Comment: Thanks for reply. But my server is not amazon and I dont have systemd problem. And the main thing I cannot use yum. Need offline procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you installed python 2.6 manually without creating a rpm package. The dependencies you see are those specified in the saltstack rpm. They are checked against the installed rpms, not the actual filesystem. If you didn't install python 2.6 as a rpm, it's normal that you have these dependencies errors.

### Install rpm without dependencies

As a solution, you may try to install the rpm without dependencies checking. That should be something like: `rpm -ivh --nodeps` but you'll most likely miss some other dependencies (python modules).

### Install manually

Or you can choose to install saltstack manually, with the sources and installation script. And you'll miss other dependencies too but you'll have to find them yourselves. Or rely on the documentation: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/installation/index.html#dependencies

### All rpm installation

Or you can install all needed rpms. Most are available in the SaltStack repository: https://repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/5Server/x86_64/latest/. You'll need at least:

- python26
- python26-ordereddict
- python26-msgpackX
- python26-six

And a few others like `python26-zmq`, `python26-tornado`, `libyaml`, `python26-jinja2` and so on. Once you have all dependencies packages, you should be good to install them all at once. Some are not required by the saltstack package and you will run into errors until you get those dependencies.

Comment: Ok. I undertsand now. `Salt only checks rpm packages`.

Comment: Actually, it's `rpm` that check the dependencies declared in the `salt` package in its own database, not in the actual filesystem.

Comment: Got it. Solved the issue. Thanks